# How can I render another scene on click button unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have two different scenes. How can I render one scene on button click in another?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [`LoadLevelAdditive`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevelAdditive.html), which will load the level and add it to the current objects. Your question is very ambiguous though.

Answer (score 0):

if you are correctly calling a new level to load and you are getting a error "Scene could not be loaded because it is not added to build settings or asset bundle has not been loaded" Make sure you add the scenes used in the project to the build settings located at File>Build settings.